# $f(x,y) \in \langle x,y \rangle$ if and only if $f(0,0)=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, polynomial-rings

I know that if $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ is such that $f(0) = 0$, then $f(x) \in \langle x \rangle$.

But while solving a problem, I encountered a polynomial $f(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $f(0,0) = 0$. Is there a nicer way to represent such polynomials ?

Relying on symmetry, intuition says that $f(x,y) \in \langle x,y \rangle$ but I can't think of a rigorous way to show this.

I think this is right because $f(0,0)=0$ $\forall$ $f(x,y) \in \langle x,y \rangle$. But how do I prove the converse ?

Comment: $\langle x,y \rangle = x \cdot f(x,y) + y \cdot g(x,y)$ where $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the polynomial explicitly:

$f(x,y)=\sum\limits_{0\leq i,j} a_{ij}x^iy^j$

Where the sum is finite. Since $f(0,0)=0$ we have $a_{00}=0$. Thus every monomial of $f$ must be divisible either by $x$ or by $y$, and so every such monomial belongs to $(x,y)$. And so $f\in (x,y)$ as well, as a sum of elements in $(x,y)$.